# Hibernate: How to properly map Sets with Composite Element containing a Many-to-one?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a mapping similar to the following:

```
<set name="tracks" table="tracks">
    <key column="album_id" />
    <composite-element class="Track">

        <many-to-one name="song" column="song_id" class="Song" cascade="none" />

        <property name="trackNumber" column="track_number" type="java.lang.Integer" not-null="false"/>
    </composite-element>
</set>
```

Generally with mappings similar to this, I've noticed that when saving the parent entity, Hibernate likes to delete all the elements of the collection first, before adding back the new elements. I've already come to accept this as standard behaviour.

However, with the mapping file I've given above, I run into an error that seems two fold.

First, Hibernate appears to be trying to delete the elements of the collection by issuing a DELETE statement using **every column** on the track table. Secondly, this still fails whenever trackNumber is null, since the DELETE statement includes a

```
DELETE FROM track WHERE album_id = ? AND song_id = ? AND track_number = ?
```

Which doesn't delete the track at all. It should really be doing for null, a

```
DELETE FROM track WHERE album_id = ? AND song_id = ? AND track_number is ?
```

**Either way, what I'd *really* like is something simple like**

```
DELETE FROM track WHERE album_id = ?
```

This seems to work when I replace the many-to-one mapping with simply the song_id

```
<set name="tracks" table="tracks">
    <key column="album_id" />
    <composite-element class="Track">

        <property name="songId" column="song_id" type="int" />

        <property name="trackNumber" column="track_number" type="java.lang.Integer" not-null="false"/>
    </composite-element>
</set>
```

But I need the track data too... any help?

Edit:

Maybe I should clarify my question.

How do I make it so my deletes on this set do not rely on trackNumber?

Comment: Why the `trackNumber` will be `null` when there is a record in db?

Comment: My real data has nothing to do with tracks and albums, this was just an analogy. Either way "trackNumber" is just some meta data that may or may not be there. The Hibernate delete-all query should not even depend on this column, and in fact doesn't seem to when I remove the many-to-one mapping... but alas, I require it...

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate issues the delete using **all columns** because you're using a collection of elements.

If you want it to use only the `album_id` and `track_id`, you need to define it as a collection of entities instead.  For this entity, you use a *composite id* of `album_id` and `track_id`.  Tracknumber then becomes just a value of your entity.

```
<set name="tracks" table="TRACK">
    <key column="album_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="Track"/>
</set>

<class name="Track">
    <composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one name="album" class="Album" column="album_id"/>
        <key-many-to-one name="song" class="Song" column="song_id"/>
    </composite-id>   
    <property name="trackNumber" column="track_number" />
</class>
```

Of course for this, I would suggest using a list instead of a set.  That way you can use the index of the list as your trackNumber.

Comment: I knew I must have been doing something wrong. I must ask though, will this sort of mapping require that the Track domain object have a back reference to the parent Album domain object?